# How to calculate cloud billing?

Tags: cloud, billing

Assume below cloud infrastructure assign to ABC company account. How to calculate average monthly bill for the ABC Company? (Assume 720 hours per month, indicate any additional assumption you made)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ2X6.png)

- 4 GB RAM, Single Core, Linux Server -  On Demand (Running only 240 hours per month) (0.08 $ per hour)
- 8 GB RAM, Two Core, Windows Server - On Demand (Running only 320 hours per month) (0.22 $ per hour)
- 4 GB, MY SQL Database Server - Dedicated (0.12 $ per hour)
- 70 GB Storage (S3) - Static (0.05 $ per GB)
- Average 0.75 GB Data Transfer Per Day (0.12 $ per GB)

Answer (score 0):

try using AWS calculator.
[SIMPLE MONTHLY CALCULATOR by AWS](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)

but if you want to understand how it compares to your current costs, you should consult with someone who can help you rethink current architecture in terms of AWS services.

e.g. when our team moved to AWS and optimised infrastructure, our budget went down by 80%

Comment: This is not regarding AWS. I just assume its AWS. It just a cloud infrastructure.